# DSO1012A Oscilloscope Agilent Technologies (Visual Studio Driver)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, driver, oscilloscope

I am trying to communicate my Visual Studio C# code with an DSO1012A Agilent Technologies Oscilloscope, but i can't find any driver, usually i download the libraries from the Keysight page and the library can support different instruments, i.e, a digital multimeter
[Keysight page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XJAb.png)
[Supported instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kFiK.png)
Even though on the page says it is for MATLAB, the driver can be used in visual studio.
The issue is i can't find any driver compatible for the DSO1012A Oscilloscope.
Anything helps!
Thank you:)

I already downloaded this driver but it doesn't work on this specific model!
https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/driver/infiniivision-xseries-oscilloscope-ivi-and-matlab-instrument-drivers-2019021.html
[Other version Oscilloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDGMT.png)

Comment: "Looking for resources" is not a good fit for the Stackoverflow Q&A model, so your question as it stands might be closed. That said, if you look at the data sheet, it says to use "National Instrument’s I/O libraries and available instrument drivers for the 1000A Series scope". Maybe you can download the drivers there?